# Mit/bei Fragen helfen

Tags: preposition

I want to send a follow-up email. I sent an e-mail to my manager with questions regarding formulas, but I did not get any answers.

I want to ask if she can help with my questions:

> Könnten Sie mir *mit* folgenden Fragen helfen?

Do we use *mit* or *bei*?

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of "B hilft A *mit* ein paar Fragen":

> A: "I don't know how to compute the distance from point (2,1) to point (6,4)."
>
> B: "Have you heard about Pythagoras' Theorem? Can you see that these points, together with (6,1), form a right triangle?"
>
> A: "Ah! Now I see!"

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is not always clearly made. Yet in principle "helfen" can go with both "bei" and "mit" with a slightly different meaning:

> jemandem bei etwas helfen

Help someone doing something. This is asking for help with an issue or task.

> jemandem mit etwas helfen

Help someone with something / Help someone by providing something. This is asking for something specific which one thinks will help. One can even combine these two modes:

> jemandem bei etwas mit etwas (anderem) helfen

To help someone doing something by doing something (else), so for instance: "Ein guter Lehrer hilft Dir beim Sprachenerwerb mit guten Lese-Empfehlungen" (a good teacher helps with learning languages by providing good reading recommendations).

All this said, in every day German the distinction is not always clearly made, and 'mit' is also used when 'bei' should be used.

Answer (score -1):

There's a bit of a difference in meaning:

"Jemandem bei etwas helfen" means something like "to help somebody at doing something". So

> Könnten Sie mir bei den folgenden Fragen helfen?

would technically mean that you need help with *asking* the questions, for example with formulating them.

On the other hand, "jemandem mit etwas helfen" means something like "to help somebody to deal with something" (among other meanings). So

> Könnten Sie mir mit den folgenden Fragen helfen?

is a bit more correct to express that you need help with *answering* the questions.

But this difference is very small. Most people would probably subconsciously "autocorrect" it if you use the wrong one here - it's probably obvious from the context whether you need help with formulating the questions or with answering them. This goes double if the recipient is aware that the sender isn't a native speaker.

Comment: Even after quite some pondering on how I remember usage and what I'd understand, I'm not entirely convinced that this distinction is really true in common usage between these two versions. If you need help asking, one would phrase it differently (in order to avoid any ambiguity, if not the given by context), like "Können Sie mir beim Formulieren der folgenden Fragen helfen?"

Comment: Wenn, dann doch umgekehrt: "Mit der Frage helfen" bedeutet eher, beim Formulieren/Rechtschreibung/Ausdruck zu helfen. Auch hört man "... in der Frage ... helfen".

Comment: @userunknown wo oder in welchem Kontext hört man "in der Frage... helfen"?

Comment: Z.B.: "Kannst Du mir in der Frage der Moderatorenrechte helfen?" - ist aber vielleicht kein sauberes Hochdeutsch. "In der Brexitfrage ..." - könnte Journalistendeutsch sein (aka. schlechtes ~).